# First select ids from one table then delete the ones that aren't those in the second table

Tags: php, mysql

What i'm trying to do is delete the rows in lobby table that don't have the ids in useronline table. that way i will be able to eliminate the ones who aren't "online". (the actual script is not about who's not online but its the same logic) Is there a way that I can first select the ids from `useronline`, then search  in `lobby` for the ones that aren't those i've just selected, and delete them with a while loop?

This is my non-working script to show you what i've got for the idea so far:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `useronline` WHERE 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {
mysql_query("DELETE * 
FROM  `lobby` 
WHERE  `tableid` NOT IN ('$row') <-- Can't figure out how to make this part
LIMIT 0 , 30");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with one query.

```
DELETE FROM  `lobby` 
WHERE  `tableid` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `useronline`)
```

Comment: Not an expert on mysql, but '*' is not valid in the delete statement I think?

Comment: therefor I've deleted it some seconds ago ;-) but thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

TO keep the code as-is, you want to change $row to $row["id"] like this:

```
WHERE  `tableid` NOT IN ('" . $row["id"] . "')
```

Comment: will this output like NOT IN (1 , 2, 3, 4) or will it first delete the ones that aren't 1, then the ones that aren't 2 and so on...

Comment: There will be so much queries executed as your SELECT finds.